# C# ASP.NET MVC - CultureInfo annotation for specific Datetime property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, cultureinfo

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project with Entity Framework using a database-first approach. I have some `Datetime` properties in my `Employee` model.

Is there a way to specify the date separator for these columns using data annotations in my metadata class? I want to display some dates using the format "dd/MM/yyyy" but they always show up like "dd-MM-yyyy".

I specified the `DataFormatString` using `{0:d}` or `{0:MM/dd/yyyy}` but there doesn't seem to be a way to specify the culture for a specific date.

```
public class EmployeeMetadata
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public System.DateTime birthdate { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public System.DateTime hiredate { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to set up the `web.config` file with the globalization property to change the culture for the entire project and the date shows the separators as expected but it's not what I want. I wish there is a way to change only a specific date of my model.